# Proving F is an Integral of the Linear Map L

Tags: dynamical-systems

In the question, I'm asked to show that 
\begin{align*}
F\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=x^2+y^2
\end{align*}
is an integral for the linear map
\begin{align*}
L(\text{x})=
\begin{pmatrix}
0&1\\-1&0
\end{pmatrix}
\text{x}.
\end{align*}

I know that to solve the exercise I need to show that F is constant along the orbits of L. That is, I need to show that $F ∘ L(x) = F(x)$.

My question is how to you compose the two in this case? In $F\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}$ Do you set both variables equal $L(x)$ or only one....

Comment: The condition "$F$ is constant along orbits of $L$" is should be written as $F\circ L(x)=F(x)$

Comment: yes sorry! thanks for pointing that out

Comment: The condition that  $F ∘ L=F$ is offtopic.

Comment: The exact question in the textbook asks you to prove that $F$ is an integral for a linear map $L$ by calculating $F ∘ L(x) = F(x)$

Comment: Which textbook is this? Are we considering the (rather poor) dynamical system in discrete time $\mathbf x_{n+1}=L(\mathbf x_n)$, or the dynamical system in continuous time $\dot{\mathbf x}(t)=L(\mathbf x(t))$?

Comment: In discrete time. The text book is 'An Introduction to Dynamical Systems' by Devaney

Comment: Then say this from the start...

Comment: Devaney does not list any book titled "An Introduction to Dynamical Systems" on his webpage.

Comment: sorry sorry! An Introduction to Chaotic Dynamical Systems

Comment: I agree with you on it being a poor question. I figured there was some element more complicated that I was missing

Comment: Exercise 6(b) (just below this one) is *much* more interesting...

Comment: I'm actually looking at that one right now. Do you have any suggestions for possibilities? :)

Answer (score 1):

The following is based on the assumption that one considers a dynamical system in continuous time. It appears that the object of interest is actually a dynamical system in discrete time (aka *a recursive sequence*...) hence the answer below does not apply. Leaving it for the picture...

Note that the question actually asks why $x^2+y^2=(-y)^2+x^2$ (?!), which makes for a *rather poor question*, I am sorry to say. Note also that every sequence $(\mathbf x_n)$ defined by $\mathbf x_{n+1}=L(\mathbf x_n)$ has period $4$, as an elementary computation shows.

---

> I know that to solve the exercise I need to show that F is constant along the orbits of L. That is, I need to show that $F \text{ o } L(x) = L(x)$.

No. That $F$ is an invariant of the dynamical system associated to $L$ means that, if $$\dot{\mathbf x}(t)=L(\mathbf x(t)),$$ then the quantity $F(\mathbf x(t))$ *does not depend on* $t$. This is usually done showing that $u'(t)=0$ for every $t$, where $$u(t)=F(\mathbf x(t)),$$ which is implied by the condition that, for every $\mathbf x$, $$\nabla F(\mathbf x)\cdot L(\mathbf x)=0.$$ In your case, $$\nabla F(\mathbf x)=2\mathbf x,$$ hence one is left with $$\nabla F(\mathbf x)\cdot L(\mathbf x)=2\mathbf x\cdot L(\mathbf x)=2\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}y\\-x\end{pmatrix}=0.$$
Here is a rough sketch of some solutions $(\mathbf x(t))$:

$\hspace2in$[image]